# neo4j query execution

Tags: neo4j

I have setup a Neo4j cluster with 5 core servers and no read replicas. I want to understand how Neo4j does load balancing and distributes the query execution. As far as I know each query issued to a cluster is executed on only one of the nodes (core/read replica) and each node will maintain a copy of the graph database. By node, I mean a machine that can either be a core server or a read replica.

In this case, in order to distribute the query execution on 5 core servers, should I query the leader node every time or should I query all the 5 core servers? Will leader node take care of directing the queries to the most available or suitable node in the cluster? Can somebody explain how the load balancing works if we have 1) only core servers in a cluster or, 2) a combination of core/read replicas in a cluster?

I have gone through the Neo4j documentation link: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/introduction/ but wasn't clear to me how the load balancing and query distribution would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's likely something we can improve upon, making sure we have an overview of routing operations in that section.

The routing doesn't happen within the cluster, but [via the driver](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/1.7/sessions-transactions/#driver-transactions-access-mode) when using the bolt+routing protocol, and when the session or transaction is explicitly marked as a WRITE or READ transaction.

When using the bolt+routing protocol, on initial connection to the cluster the driver will request and obtain a routing table so it knows which nodes in the cluster have what roles (this table is updated periodically). The driver will use this table to route transactions that are explicitly created as READ or WRITE transactions in the code.

WRITE transactions will always be routed to the leader. READ transactions will be routed to one of the follower or read replica nodes, using a round-robin approach (unless configured otherwise).